# Getting Date form three combo boxes as dd/mm/yyyy using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, combobox, date-conversion

i can't get datetime from 3 comboboxes, i just can full it with for loop but it's wrong when the condition is stop):

so how to get DateTime object form three comboboxes as dd/mm/yyyy ,
combobox1 for day,
cobmobox2 for month and
combobox3 for year

```
{
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//date of birth
this.comboBox3.Leave += new EventHandler(comboBox3_Leave);
this.comboBox1.Leave += new EventHandler(comboBox3_Leave);
this.comboBox2.Leave += new EventHandler(comboBox3_Leave);

for (int i = 1950; i < 2012; i++)
{
comboBox3.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}

for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
{
comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}

comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
}
```

and i create a event "Leave" for combobox3

```
 private void comboBox3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 int day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text), 
 comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 1);
 if (day <= comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
 {
 //alert message or your managing code.
 }

 }
```

the error is 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'value InvalidArgument of '0' is not vaild for 'SelectedIndex'.
the selcted index of month

Answer (score 1):

`comboBox2` is not initialized with items. Since `comboBox2` does not have any items and you are trying to select the first item in `comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;` it crashes.

Add `comboBox2.Items.Add("Test");` somewhere before `comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;` and it should "work". And when your code is working you can add the proper item to comboBox2.

Comment: `comboBox2.Items.Add("January");`, `comboBox2.Items.Add("February");` and `comboBox2.Items.Add("Mars");`. It's not the best way, but I think it is the best way to start.